# How do I make an autocomplete search bar for FAQ page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create an autocomplete search bar, that gives me suggestions base on multiple words (so, for example "win of the day" doesn't require me to write "win" first. If I write "day" and then "win", this option would still appear. And then, when I select one suggestion, the page scrolls to that FAQ question.

I have been trying with JS and Jquery (which I am not familiar with).
Some incomplete examples:

- http://jsfiddle.net/uLq7wgkp/ (doesn't have autocomplete)
  `<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/uLq7wgkp/embed/"></script>`
- https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple (doesn't show me how to make it scroll to the faq question in the page.
- [Multiple words autocomplete filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63113525/multiple-words-autocomplete-filtering/70318040#70318040) (this one doesn't show how to scroll to question either).

Comment: You are looking for a "Fuzzy search", which would depend on the backend, and not the front end IMO.
That said, heres a bunch of fuzzy search libraries for JS
https://bashooka.com/coding/javascript-fuzzy-search-libraries/#:~:text=%2010%20Awesome%20Javascript%20Fuzzy%20Search%20Libraries%20,string%20with%20partial%20input%2C%20useful%20for...%20More%20

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript fuzzy search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206013/javascript-fuzzy-search)

Comment: Hey, hm.. I will have to look into it!